# Resampled data Does not show any value for target class after applying SMOTE

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, smote

I am a bie in ML and i am trying to implement SMOTE on the PIDD dataset for diabetes prediction.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
#os =  SMOTE()
X = exTrans.drop(['Outcome'], axis=1)
y = exTrans['Outcome']
sm = SMOTE(random_state=42, k_neighbors=5)
X_smote, y_smote = sm.fit_resample(X, y)

### This resamples the dataset for SMOTE technique
X_smote.shape,y_smote.shape
```

In the code above after resampling the data i get the output below:

```
((1000, 8), (1000,))
```

the first part of the output is for `X_smote.shape`, which is fine; but the `y_smote.shape` output is not complete it only shows (1000, ) and the second parameter is missing.
I feel that i am missing something, is it supposed to have any value there? If yes how do i make it happen?

Comment: `(1000,)` is a tuple containing one element, 1000. The comma is there to avoid ambiguity with just 1000 wrapped in braces.

Comment: Thank you, i spent the whole time looking for an error that don't exist.

Comment: Any Idea on how to build a GAN for tabular data, specifically Pima Indian Diabetes Dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Test you data with the following code:

```
# SMOTE for imbalanced dataset
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from matplotlib import pyplot
from numpy import where
# define dataset
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=10000, n_features=2, n_redundant=0,
 n_clusters_per_class=1, weights=[0.99], flip_y=0, random_state=1)
# summarize class distribution
counter = Counter(y)
print(counter)
# transform the dataset
oversample = SMOTE()
X_sm, y_sm = oversample.fit_resample(X, y)
# summarize the new class distribution
counter = Counter(y_sm)
print(counter)
```